# Get same bump from a photo to a model

Tags: normal-map, displacement, height-map

I've been tinkering with this for a while but can't seem to find a good answer to my problem. I need to recreate the Activity Center from Fisher Price photo-realistically and I'm not sure how to go around the small bump details it has. I've been trying with a normal map I got from a photograph and it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I don't know why it sometimes flips even if I didn't change anything. Also it's not giving me the quality I need.
I've tried getting a displacement map using CrazyBump but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly?

With normal map after it flips itself:
[image]
Correct normal map (but still not good enough):
[image]

Displacement map I get from CrazyBump:
[image]

It just messes everything up, doesn't even add the details or anything. I find weird how it would do that given that the map itself is all blurry but it seems good in it's preview ??
[image]

Am I missing something? Is there another way? Since it's for rendering I don't really care for how to achieve it if it works. I'm using Marmoset Toolbag for rendering but Blender for the model and stuff.

Comment: Have your tried inverting the bump map values? Depending on your mesh rotation, it could be inwards or outwards depending on your values.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do every time the normal map flips, but even when the normal map is working correctly the quality of how it looks is not enough for what I need. The normal map has the correct definition and everything but not enough for how prominent the bump is.

Comment: instead of a bump map try a displacement modifier.

Comment: @cegation I did try it, didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Marmoset Toolbag, so I can't speak for that part. But there should be a setting in there somewhere that you can adjust the strength of your bump map. It is the settings in your 3rd screenshot I believe.

In blender it works like this at least, notice the first image has a high strength on the clouds, the second has a lowered value for the clouds.
[image]
[image]

I don't believe this is a question related to Blender however since you use a 3rd party renderer, and it's the renderer that handles bump maps and such.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to render in Blender with a common normal map but my problem is that using a NM is not up to the quality I need since it needs to be a little bit more realistic and the bump is very prominent for it to be made through a NM. I would like to use it to create either a high poly version or a displacement map that gives a better result. I'm asking in Blender because that's the main program I'm using but also trying with Marmoset. Thank you anyway though

Comment: If the resoultion is too small for your liking, simply make it higher res

Comment: It's not the resolution, it's the way normal maps work. I need geometry there, either by a displacement map or actual geometry.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. But the map you already have should work for displacement too